# In JS, modify function in more university

Tags: javascript

I have a function for fetch data. But how can made this function more universal? For example, else quantity of arguments would be change.

```
var url = [
  'http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cevhxOsZnS',
  'http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cguaPsRxAi',
  'http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cfDZdmxnDm'
]

fetchData(...url)

function fetchData(a, b, c) {
  var arr = [];
  fetch(a)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {
      arr.push(res)
      return fetch(b)
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {
      arr.push(res)
      return fetch(c)
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => arr.push(res))
    .then(res => console.log(arr))
}
```

Comment: `return Promise.all(urls.map(url => fetch(url).then(res => res.json())));`

Comment: This isn't correct. It shoots three different isolated promises. OP's responses are connected to the previous response

Comment: okay they aren't. apologies. Also, answers are meant to be posted in comments

Answer (score 0):

From looking at your code, I am assuming that `fetch` is a function that takes an URL as input and returns a Promise.

You can make use of the fact that the `arguments` keyword in javascript contains all the arguments with which the function was called and make a recursive function to do what you want.

Example code for that would be like this:

```js
var url = [
  'http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cevhxOsZnS',
  'http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cguaPsRxAi',
  'http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cfDZdmxnDm'
]

fetchData(...url)

function fetchData() {
  var arr = [];
  fetchRecursive(arguments, arr);
}

function fetchRecursive (args, arr, i = 0) {
  if (i < args.length - 1) {
    return fetch(args[i])
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => {
        arr.push(res);
        return fetchRecursive(args[++i]);
      });
  } else {
    return fetch(args[i])
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => {
        arr.push(res);
        console.log(arr);
      });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution with a generator and async / await.

```js
var url = [
  'http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cevhxOsZnS',
  'http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cguaPsRxAi',
  'http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cfDZdmxnDm'
];


function* fetchData(urls) {
  var result = [];
  for (someUrl of urls) {
    console.log("Fetching ", someUrl);
    yield new Promise((resolve) => {
      fetch(someUrl).then(res => {
        res.json().then(res => {
          result.push(res);
          resolve();
        });
      })
    });
  }
  return result;
}

async function asyncCall() {
  var iterator, iteration;
  iterator = fetchData(url);

  do {
    iteration = iterator.next();
    await iteration.value;
  } while (!iteration.done);

  console.log("done ", iteration.value);
}

asyncCall();
```